# Why do I not get a deadlock when trying to read from a channel that never receives data in a goroutine but do in the main func

Tags: go, concurrency, deadlock, goroutine

Why do I get a deadlock here

```
c := make(chan bool)
fmt.Println(<-c)
fmt.Println("done")
```

and not here

```
c := make(chan bool)
go func() {
    fmt.Println(<-c)
}()
fmt.Println("done")
```

I was expecting a deadlock in both cases because both are trying to read from a channel that is never going to receive data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The child goroutine is blocked, but the current goroutine can proceed with its execution.

You get a deadlock only when *all* goroutines are blocked at the same time.